# How to resolve the library catalog error: "Request data is missing. Please try again."

Tags: firefox, website, cookies

(The Toronto Public Library, like various other libraries, [uses](https://torontopubliclibrary.typepad.com/trl/2017/11/trl-40-years-catalog-from-paper-to-online-.html) a [library software suite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_library_system) named SirsiDynix Symphony.  This software suite includes various modules, including an online catalogue.)

I was using the Toronto Public Library's online catalogue in Mozilla Firefox 91.9.0esr.  Whenever I attempted to place a hold, I got the error message:

"Request data is missing. Please try again."

What's the correct way to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on a suggestion from the library staff, the solution is to **clear all cookies from the library's website**.

I tried this, and it worked.

- In Firefox, if you'd like to clear all library-related cookies, follow [these instructions](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/clear-cookies-and-site-data-firefox#w_clear-cookies-for-the-current-website).
- If you're using another Web browser, see [these other instructions](https://www.lifewire.com/clear-cookies-for-one-site-4587347).
- If either of the aforementioned links no longer works, you might want to try a Web search for [ [`how to clear cookies for the current website`](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+clear+cookies+for+the+current+website) ] instead.

(Alternatively, if you prefer, you can clear all cookies from **all** websites.  However, this may log you out of many websites.  In order to log back in, you'll need to remember your username and password for each website.)